# Laravel write file stream

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am using `guzzle` to downlaod file from url and save it into my storage.

So I have a code look like this

```
        $response = $this->client->request('GET', $model->url, [
            'stream' => true
        ]);

        $body = $response->getBody();

        while (!$body->eof()) {
            Storage::append($this->filePath, $body->read(1024));;
        }
```

but when I open the folder where my file is located, I see that the file size is changing and sometimes it is zero. So in the end I am getting a invalid file.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How large is the file? Have you attempted to use `file_get_contents()` instead?

Comment: Files can be have a different sizes. Now I am testing file with size 54mb. I have also tried to use   `file_get_contents()` function and the result have same. but I would like to use laravel sotrage.

Comment: How come you have opted to used `Storage::append` instead of `Storage::put`?

Comment: I think my problem comes from guzzle. because I am using `Storage::put`,`Storage::append` and `file_get_contents()`, and getting same resultat. In the end I am always getting invalid file

Comment: Which verson of `guzzle` are you using?

Comment: Have you tried `$response->getBody()->getContents()`?

Comment: I am using Guzzle:"6.3". No ,I have not used , Here is a link of docs http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#stream